# Estoy realizando bien la consulta, o me estoy comiendo toda la RAM

Tags: java, android

queria consultaros unas dudas que tengo en el codigo. Como vereis en el onCreate de mi MainActivity, tengo una clase que llama a un Runnable. Mi consulta es, ¿Puede estar consumiendo toda la RAM del Servidor?, porque estoy teniendo problemas y sospecho que los problemas vendran de por aqui. Y si fuese correcto mis sospechas, ¿como podria solucionarlo?, para que no este cada 1segundo realizando la consulta al JSON. Si hay alguna forma de guardar todos los datos del JSON para despues trabajarlo y asi no consumir la memoria RAM del Servidor.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToastRunnable.run();
}

private Runnable mToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("URL_SERVIDOR")
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String json = response.body().string();
                Gson gson = new Gson();

                [...]

                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta de aplicar esta lógica es creando un asynctask y cuando recibas los datos del servidor guardarlos en la BBDD de sqlite, te dejo la clase para realizar la asyncTask correctamente. Para este tipo de situaciones es remcomendable usar el AsyncTask en lugar de Threads.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String mRequestedURL;

    public JsonTask(String requestedURL){
        mRequestedURL = requestedURL;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(mRequestedURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");
                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + line);

            }
            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

**Para ejecutarla**

```
new JsonTask("url del servidor").execute();
```